# Ruby passing values into method? Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

New to ruby with selenium but basically what I want to do is pass  `contact['rob', 'email', 'subject', 'message']` into

```
def contact(name="Default", email="Default", subject="Default", message="Default")
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @subject = subject
    @message = message
```

and then if values match up run code below:

```
 if(name == 'rob' && email == 'email' && subject == 'subject' && message == 'message')
  name_field = driver.find_element :css => ('#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
  name_field.click
  name_field.send_keys(name)

  email_field = driver.find_element :css =>  '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input'
  email_field.click
  email_field.send_keys(email)

  subject_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input'
  subject_field.click
  subject_field.send_keys(subject)

  message_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea'
  message_field.click
  message_field.send_keys(message)
    else
      puts 'failed'
      end
  end
```

Full Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class Standard_web_driver_test2

  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.get 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  driver.manage.window.maximize
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5)



  def contact(name="Default", email="Default", subject="Default", message="Default")
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @subject = subject
    @message = message
    if(name == 'rob' && email == 'email' && subject == 'subject' && message == 'message')
  name_field = driver.find_element :css => ('#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
  name_field.click
  name_field.send_keys(name)

  email_field = driver.find_element :css =>  '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input'
  email_field.click
  email_field.send_keys(email)

  subject_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input'
  subject_field.click
  subject_field.send_keys(subject)

  message_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea'
  message_field.click
  message_field.send_keys(message)
    else
      puts 'failed'
      end
  end

  contact['rob', 'email', 'subject', 'message']
end
```

I am sure there is an easier way of doing this but just trying to get used to using blocks with code.

Error Message: ': undefined local variable or method `contact' for Standard_web_driver_test2:Class (NameError)

New Code before with global Variables:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class StandardWebdriverTest2

  @@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  @@driver.get 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  @@driver.manage.window.maximize
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5)



  def self.contact(name="Default", email="Default", subject="Default", message="Default")
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @subject = subject
    @message = message
    if(name == 'rob' && email == 'email' && subject == 'subject' && message == 'message')
  name_field = @@driver.find_element :css => ('#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
  name_field.click
  name_field.send_keys(name)

  email_field = @@driver.find_element :css =>  '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input'
  email_field.click
  email_field.send_keys(email)

  subject_field = @@driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input'
  subject_field.click
  subject_field.send_keys(subject)

  message_field = @@driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea'
  message_field.click
  message_field.send_keys(message)
    else
      puts 'failed'
    end

  end

  contact('rob', 'email', 'subject', 'message')
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name should be something like

```
class StandardWebdriverTest2
```

As per naming convention

```
Class and Module 
Classes and modules use MixedCase and have no underscores, each word starts with a uppercase letter, e.g. InvoiceItem
```

You can find some suggestion on this naming convention [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)

Secondly you call contact method inside class

Then you need to make it class method

```
class StandardWebdriverTest2
   #your code rest of the code
   def self.contact(name="Default", email="Default", subject="Default", message="Default")
      #your code for contact
   end
 contact("","","","") # call contact method
 end
```

otherwise you get error  `undefined local variable or method "contact" for Standard_web_driver_test2:Class (NameError)`

Comment: Thanks :) I have no errors no in console when run, however, name_field.send_keys(name) values aren't being pushed in so must be something else

Comment: yes this is something web driver functionality problem .....suggestion is please check name_filed is getting select properly to send keys on it

Comment: Web-driver code works outside of the method block but once inside does not run :( @Rajarshi Das

Comment: ok got it your `driver` define outside a class it should be a class variable make it `@@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` and then replace all `driver` to `@@driver` after this it would like `@@driver.find_element :css => ('#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')`

Comment: above will solve this problem might be but I prefer `initialize` and `attr_reader`  for a class design to access

Comment: This did not work but I think I understand your logic. Still no error. Do you suggest putting this code in def initialize driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.get 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  driver.manage.window.maximize
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5)
end

?

Comment: I will post updated code in morning, sorry I've just left work and it's on the work machine. Thanks.

Comment: you should call contact outside of the method not inside of the method

Comment: copy and paste the edited last answer and check it should working

Comment: That has worked need to remember to call method outside of method. thanks a lot.